# Asymptotic variance of Metropolis-Hastings estimates on a disjoint subdivision of the state space

Tags: variance, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings, stratification

I'm running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm on a state space $(E,\mathcal E)$ which can be disjointly subdivided into regions $E_1,\ldots,E_k$, $k\in\mathbb N$ ($k\approx1e5$). On $E$, I have a measure $\lambda$ and a nonnegative function $f$ and need to estimate the integrals $\lambda(1_{E_1}f),\ldots,\lambda(1_{E_k}f)$.

I'm doing this using the [importance sampling estimator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf). The target distribution of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm has a (unnormalized) density $p$ with respect to $\lambda$ with $c:=\lambda p\in(0,\infty)$ and $\{p=0\}\subseteq\{f=0\}$. (**EDIT**: If it simplifies the problem, you can assume that $f=p$.)

The asymptotic variance of my estimate to $\lambda(1_{E_j}f)$ is of the form $$\sigma^2_j:=\sum_{i\in I}\int\mu({\rm d}x)w_i(x)\int\lambda({\rm d}y)\frac{\left|1_{E_j}(y)f(y)-\frac{p(y)}c\lambda(1_{E_j}f)\right|^2}{q_i(y)u'_i\left(\varphi_i^{-1}(x),\varphi_i^{-1}(y)\right)},$$ where $I\subseteq\mathbb N$ is finite and nonempty and the $w_i:E\to[0,1]$ are measurable weights satisfying $\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1$ which I want to choose so that $\max_{1\le j\le k}\sigma^2_j$ is minimized. The remaining details$^1$ don't matter. The important aspect is that that for a fixed $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ the variance $\sigma^2_j$ is minimized by choosing $w_i(x)=1$ for the single $i\in I$ minimizing the inner integral $\int\lambda({\rm d}y)\frac{\left|1_{E_j}(y)f(y)-\frac{p(y)}c\lambda(1_{E_j}f)\right|^2}{q_i(y)u'_i\left(\varphi_i^{-1}(x),\varphi_i^{-1}(y)\right)}$ (if there are multiple such $i$ pick the smallest one) and $w_j(x)=0$ for all other $j\in I\setminus\{i\}$.

> As the optimal choice of weights depends on the region $E_j$, I'm not sure what I should do. Should I try to find a bound on $\max_{1\le j\le k}\sigma^2_j$ and do the same analysis as before to find an optimal choice of the weights minimizing this bound? This might be hard and it's not guaranteed that the individual "per-region" variances are significantly reduced.
>
> Alternatively, I could compute all the optimal choices for the individual subregions and pick the choice minimizing the variance the most subregions.
>
> Or should I split the algorithm by running a separate Metropolis-Hastings instance on clusters $C_1,\ldots,C_l$ of the subregions? (For example, $C_1=\{E_1,E_2,E_3\},C_2=\{E_4,E_5,E_6\}$ and so on). Doing this would still yield the same question as before, but maybe it's more sensible since each cluster can be assumed occupy only a small part of the whole state space $E$. In the degenerate case, I could even run a separate chain on each subregion.

There are notions as the [mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) which seem to be related.

**EDIT**: Assuming $f=p$, note that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sigma^2_j&=\left(c-2\lambda\left(1_{E_j}p\right)\right)\sum_{i\in I}\int\mu({\rm d}x)w_i(x)\int_{E_j}\mu({\rm d}y)\frac{p(y)}{q_i(y)u'_i\left(\varphi_i^{-1}(x),\varphi_i^{-1}(y)\right)}\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+\frac{\left|\lambda\left(1_{E_j}p\right)\right|^2}c\sum_{i\in I}\int\mu({\rm d}x)w_i(x)\int\mu({\rm d}y)\frac{p(y)}{q_i(y)u'_i\left(\varphi_i^{-1}(x),\varphi_i^{-1}(y)\right)}\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} and you can assume that $$c-2\lambda\left(1_{E_j}p\right)\ge0\tag2.$$

*Remark*: Please take note of my related question of how I can compute the index $j$ minimizing $\sigma^2_j$: https://mathoverflow.net/q/356564/91890.

---

$^1$ $q_1,\ldots,q_k$ are probability denities on $E$ with respect to $\lambda$, each $\varphi_j$ is a mapping from another measure space $(E'_j,\mathcal E'_j,\lambda'_j)$ to $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ satisfying $\lambda'\circ\varphi_j=q_j\lambda$ and each $u'_j$ is the density of a Markov kernel on  $(E'_j,\mathcal E'_j)$ with respect to $\lambda'_j$. You can assume $E'_j=[0,1)^{d_j}$ for some $d_j\in\mathbb N$, $\mathcal E'_j=\mathcal B(E_j)$ and $\lambda'_j$ being the Lebesgue measure on $E_j$. Moreover, $u'_j$ can be assumed to be of the form $u'_j(x',y')=\prod_{k=1}^{d_j}v'(x'_k,y'_k)$ for some density $v'$ of a Markov kernel on $([0,1),\mathcal B([0,1))$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$.